# How to register custom type to type mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want to register a custom type to JDBC so that when I call `setObject` in `PreparedStatement`, it can automatically recognize this type and know how to serialize type to SQL data.

I've got some clues from this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html#implementing_sqldata, but there are still a few points not clear to me:

1. what I want to register is `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon`, which is a type from third party library, so implementing `SQLData` seems not a good idea for me, since I don't have access to class source code
2. In the tutorial example, the type is registered per connection, is there any way to register this mapping globally?

Comment: Such options are not defined in JDBC (other than using `SQLData`, which is not supported by some drivers), but possibly there could be driver specific extensions. What database system are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm using Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Postgres JDBC does not support SQLData but you can use org.postgresql.util.PGobject. There are several reference implementation e.g. org.postgresql.geometric.PGpolygon. It is still required to register per connection. Imho this approach has no sense for custom types in postgres. You should implement conversation from object to string and from string to object and use setString/getString methods in JDBC API. E.g. for custom type string pair `create type string_pair AS (first text, second text);`  Postgres string will be: `"('string1', 'string2')"` (do not forget to escape symbols in this string). Later you can write: `"insert into ...(?::string_pair, ..."` and set value by `preparedStmt.setString(1, convertToStr(myPair));`